# Dummy variable from two columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I'm new to Python, so my question may be very basic, sorry// 
I'm struggling to create one dummy variable on two columns in Python. I have a column(**died**) which is a dummy on its own with 1 corresponding to a death, 0 - no death. The second column is **'Age'** that tells the age of death in months. What i need is to create a dummy for children who died before 5  years (**'died'==1 & 'Age' < 60**) and a dummy for children who died before 1 year (**'died' == 1 & Age' < 12**). I usually work in Stata in which this is very easy, but in Python I am struggling. I've been trying to use get_dummies function from pandas:
 `dummy= pd.get_dummies(df['died']) & (df.aad < 60.).astype('int')` 
but it returns an error that it can't perform add, my guess is that it can't add indicator variable'died' with a continuous variable 'aad'.  Is there a straightforward (beginner friendly) way to combine information from two columns to generate a new dummy variable? Thanks a lot!

Comment: why the `astype('int')` and what is `aad`

Comment: astype('int')  is what i found in google on how to convert continuous variables into dummies, "aad" is just a variable name

Answer (score 1):

import numpy as np

df['dummy'] = np.where((df['died']==1) & (df['aad']<60), 1, 0)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this pretty easily this way:

```
dummy = ((df['died'] == 1) & (df['aad'] < 60)).astype('int')
```